# Spark - Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I need to write Spark sql query with inner select and partition by. Problem is that I have AnalysisException.
I already spend few hours on this but with other approach I have no success.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;
Window [sum(cast(_w0#41 as bigint)) windowspecdefinition(deviceId#28, timestamp#30 ASC NULLS FIRST, RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grp#34L], [deviceId#28], [timestamp#30 ASC NULLS FIRST]
+- Project [currentTemperature#27, deviceId#28, status#29, timestamp#30, wantedTemperature#31, CASE WHEN (status#29 = cast(false as boolean)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS _w0#41]
```

I assume that this is too complicated query to implement like this. But i don't know to to fix it.

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkUtils.getSparkSession("RawModel");

 Dataset<RawModel> datasetMap = readFromKafka(spark);

 datasetMap.registerTempTable("test");

 Dataset<Row> res = datasetMap.sqlContext().sql("" +
                " select deviceId, grp, avg(currentTemperature) as averageT, min(timestamp) as minTime ,max(timestamp) as maxTime, count(*) as countFrame " +
                " from (select test.*,  sum(case when status = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by deviceId order by timestamp) as grp " +
                "  from test " +
                "  ) test " +
                " group by deviceid, grp ");
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I am also getting same error, did you get any solution.

Comment: I did not. I implemented from beginning with different approach. I used custom aggregation.

Comment: You mean, pandas_udf ?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is in the *windowing* specification:

```
over (partition by deviceId order by timestamp)
```

The *partition* would need to be over a time based column - in your case *timestamp* .  The following should work:

```
over (partition by timestamp order by timestamp)
```

That will not of course address the *intent* of your query. The following might be attempted: but it is unclear whether spark would support it:

```
over (partition by timestamp, deviceId order by timestamp)
```

Even if spark *does* support that it would still change the semantics of your query.

***Update***

Here is a  definitive source: from *Tathagata Das* who is a key/core committer on *spark streaming*:  http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Does-partition-by-and-order-by-works-only-in-stateful-case-td31816.html

[image]

Comment: As on 2021 and Spark 3.0, `over (partition by timestamp order by timestamp) ` isnt working yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70062355/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-non-time-based-windows-are-not-supported