# Adding a ROW_NUMBER column to a streaming dataframe

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, sql-order-by, spark-streaming, row-number

I'm fairly new to Spark and SQL. I am trying to add a column to my df (which I will then save to a Delta table) that gives a unique id to each record/row and increments it every that specific record is updated.

I was trying to do the following:

```
SELECT etc,
CONCAT(somerows1) as id1,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY somerows1 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS versionid
FROM etc
```

somerows1 being the concatenation of several columns in order to form a unique record. I have no particular interest in the records being ordered in a particular form, that's why I chose ORDER BY (SELECT NULL).

I get the following error:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets; line 1 pos 0;
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294809/spark-non-time-based-windows-are-not-supported-on-streaming-dataframes-dataset) suggests, maybe the problem is that you need to specify a time-based column in the partition.

Comment: @Let'stry I have tried adding a timestamp column to the partition and I still get the same error

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this problem by using the [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) sink on the `.writeStream`. This allows you to create a functon where the streaming dataframe is treated like a static/batch dataframe (the function is applied to each micro-batch).

In Scala the code would look something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{row_number, lit}

val saveWithWindowFunction = (sourceDf: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {

  val windowSpec = Window
    .partitionBy("somerows1") 
    .orderBy(lit(null))
  
  sourceDf
    .withColumn("versionid", row_number().over(windowSpec))

//... save the dataframe using: sourceDf.write.save()
}
```

With the `.writeStream` calling your function:

```
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .foreachBatch(saveWithWindowFunction)
  .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is aggregations over a sliding event-time window. Check the documentation and examples [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time).