# Can we use row_number() in PySpark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

The [PySpark SQL functions reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) on the `row_number()` function says

> returns a sequential number starting at 1 within a window partition

implying that the function works only on windows. Trying

```py
df.select('*', row_number())
```

predictably gives a

```
Window function row_number() requires an OVER clause
```

exception.

Now, `.over()` seems to work only with [WindowSpec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html) because

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import window, row_number
...
df.select('*', row_number().over(window('time', '5 minutes')))
```

gives a

```
TypeError: window should be WindowSpec
```

exception.
However, according to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37439?focusedCommentId=17447616&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17447616) comment on the ASF Jira:

> By time-window we described what time windows are supported in SS natively.
> http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#types-of-time-windows
>
> Window spec is not supported. This defines the boundary of window as non-timed manner, the offset(s) of the row, which is hard to track in streaming context.

WindowSpec is generally not supported in Structured Streaming. Leading to the conclusion that the `row_number()` function is not supported in Structured Streaming. Is that correct? Just want to make sure I'm not missing anything here.

Comment: Not an answer attempt, but I think there is a bit of confusion between [`winodw()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window) SQL function and [`Window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/window.html) class.

Comment: Not confusion, but intention: I was trying to use the `window()` SQL function instead of the `Window` class because the latter returns a `WindowSpec` which is not supported in Structured Streaming (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294809 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490147).

Answer (score 1):

first point, your imports are wrong:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
```

second, try doing like this:

```
partition_columns = Window.partitionBy(
    df.column1,
    df.column2,
    ...
).orderBy(df.col...)

df = df.withColumn('your_new_column_rank', row_number().over(partition_columns))
```

Usually we use Windowing functions to deduplicate records in Structured Streaming, the documentation says that is not possible to use it because this function will not access the already saved data as we can do with Batch, but you can set watermark, like this:

```
df = df.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes").withColumn('your_new_column_rank', row_number().over(partition_columns))
```

or even you can try using watermark to run drop_duplicate function.

Another way to do it, is through the foreachBatch

```
def func(batch_df, batch_id):
    partition_columns = Window.partitionBy(
      df.column1,
      df.column2,
      ...
    ).orderBy(batch_df.col...)

    batch_df= batch_df.withColumn('your_new_column_rank', 
    row_number().over(partition_columns))
    ...

writer = sdf.writeStream.foreachBatch(func)
```

Like above you will have a micro df that is not a Structured Streaming DF, so there is possible to access functions that you can't with a a streaming one.

Comment: I was trying to use the `window()` SQL function instead of the `Window` class because `Window.partitionBy()` returns a `WindowSpec` which is not supported in Structured Streaming (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294809 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490147). Also, I don't want the `row_number()` over partitions but the whole data set. Using the `foreach` or `foreachBatch` sink would work, of course, but then I cannot leverage checkpointing to make my job restartable after a crash.

Comment: PS: Because in the micro batch handler I would have to keep the row count as an internal state which will not be included in Spark's checkpointing.

Comment: Instead of keeping as an internal state you can retrieve your current saved data, apply the function and the just save or merge it again, but yes, it's one of the challenges when working on with structured streaming